# Azure python SDK: How to get a list of all Virtual Networks which contained in a Resource Group?

Tags: python, azure, sdk

I am reletive new to Azure python SDK, and I have a basic question.

My goal is simple: Given a resource group name, I want create a variables list of
type List[VirtualNetwork] which are all the virtual networks in that resource group.

looking in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.operations.virtualnetworksoperations?view=azure-python#list-resource-group-name----kwargs-) microsoft documentetion, the 'VirtualNetworksOperations' class have a 'list' method
which "Gets all virtual networks in a resource group."

The return type if this method is 'ItemPaged[VirtualNetworkListResult]'.
ItemPaged is some kind of iterator, so I can get a 'VirtualNetworkListResult' object from it.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models.virtualnetworklistresult?view=azure-python) microsoft documentetion, it is not clear if the described parameters (which include the type List[VirtualNetwork]) are also the instance attribute or not.

If the answer is no, Is there any way to retrive what I want from that object?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

> The return type if this method is
> `ItemPaged[VirtualNetworkListResult]`. `ItemPaged` is some kind of
> iterator, so I can get a '`VirtualNetworkListResult`' object from it.
>
> According to this Microsoft documentation, it is not clear if the
> described parameters (which include the type `List[VirtualNetwork]`)
> are also the instance attribute or not.

[`VirtualNetworksOperations.list` operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.operations.virtualnetworksoperations?view=azure-python#list-resource-group-name----kwargs-)  indeed returns an *iterator object*  where `VirtualNetworkListResult` conforms to an *object type* which only instructs [`Deserializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrest/msrest.serialization.deserializer?view=azure-python) which type(model) response object gets deserialized into.

From usage perspective no extra work is needed to manipulate `VirtualNetworkListResult`, the following example demonstrates how to return list of `VirtualNetwork` instances:

```
vn_it = network_client.virtual_networks.list(res_name)
vn_list = list(vn_it)
```

**Complete sample**

```
credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(
    credential=credential,
    subscription_id=subscription_id
)

vn_it = network_client.virtual_networks.list(res_name)
for vn in vn_it:
    print(vn.name)
```